# Pushforward of tensor product of holomorphic vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, grothendieck-riemann-roch

Let $M$ be a complex manifold, $\Sigma$ a Riemann surface of genus $g$, and $E, F$ holomorphic vector bundles on $M\times\Sigma$. If $\pi: M\times \Sigma\to M$ is the projection map, is it possible to express the pushforward $\pi_!(E\otimes F)$ in terms $\pi_!(E)$ and $\pi_!(F)$?

Comment: Where do your vector bundles live?

Comment: @abx Thanks for asking. They live on $M\times\Sigma$. I have just made the correction.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer to your question is your username...

Comment: Take for $M$ the Jacobian of $\Sigma $. Let $E$ be the Poincaré line bundle (such that $E_{|\{\alpha \}\times \Sigma  }=\alpha $), and let $F:=E^{-1}$. Then $\pi _*E=\pi _*F=0$, but $\pi _*(E\otimes F)=\mathcal{O}_M$. Variations on this theme give all sorts of vector bundles for $\pi _*(E\otimes F)$,  still with $\pi _*E=\pi _*F=0$.

Comment: ... or take $M$ to be a point, $E=$ a line bundle of degree one with no sections. Some tensor power $F=E^{\otimes k}$ will have sections.